# parse json data inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, json

hi i am new in json and php, i try to parse json data inside while loop in php, but it returns empty.

please help. here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/i9z7YBwY

here is my table data

```
|id|data|
_________
|11|[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Company","value":"Destination Queenstown"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Your Name","value":"Ella Zhang"}]|
_________
|12|[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Company","value":"New Company"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Your Name","value":"Michael"}]|
_________
|13|[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Company","value":"Blitzc inc"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Your Name","value":"Yudha"}]|
_________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the second parameter to `true`, to tell it to return the result as an associative array.

```
$array = json_decode($array, true);
```

This is quite clearly documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in the PHP manual.

You can then access `value` like this:

```
$array['value']
```

Comment: i put true but nothing is happen

Comment: You need to use it like an array after you make the change.

Comment: I have added it to my answer.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea this code working fine in my PC. Probably error in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `table` is reserved MySQL word. Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, data FROM `table`";
```

And then for me all your code work well

Comment: i used table just for an example, the true table name is not "table"

Comment: @Haris in my local PC your code work correct. So please add MySQL structure of your table and data DUMP with couple rows. Because i don't see there any error.

Comment: hi stepozer, problem solved, the problem was on my machine. and yes the code was working file. thank you